# Why am I getting this error when updating after a partial upgrade?

Tags: vlc, partial-upgrade

I was prompted for a partial upgrade and I completed it. During this, VLC was removed. When I try to reinstall it I get this:

```
isuru@isuru-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc   
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested 
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some 
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
vlc: 
Depends:
vlc-nox (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Broken packages 

isuru@isuru-desktop:~$

sudo apt-get install vlc-nox 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
out of Incoming. 

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
vlc-nox: 
Depends:
libavformat52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but it is not going to be installed or libavformat-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) 
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: If you've upgraded to a later Ubuntu version, I should disable the Lucid ppa that keeps popping up. Then you should be able to run `sudo apt-get update` and install vlc without having two conflicting sources of the package available.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once that is complete, open your software center and type `vlc` in the search field and follow the remaining steps as you would normally.

Comment: itz not working

Comment: Sorry there is one more command we need to do.
I've added.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

> sudo apt-get install -f

Does that fix it?